# How is detector able to separate EM wave with specific frequency?

Tags: waves

My imagination about EM waves is that they sum together when they meet (that superposition principle) and i struggle to understand the concept how is it possible that change in frequency allows us to read just the signal we are interested in (differentiate between two signals if they have different frequencies).

If i have two different EM waves (different frequencies) then i can observer just the amplitude of sum of these waves no? I know that this is not true otherwise we would not be able to have radios, wifi, ... but i still can't understand how the detector when it observes value 50 knows that only 20 is from the signal it is interested in (how frequency helps in this if you just have the sum of amplitudes??)

Im jumping from topic to topic and don't know where exactly i should start to understand these stuffs. Im just curios studying it for my own interest.

Thanks for anything that can help me to understand this.

Comment: a frequency sensitive detector is preceded by a "color" filter

Comment: @hyportnex: I know our eyes are "detectors" too but i can't figure out how it can work if what you get is just one signal that is sum of all the signals at that place. I see no reason why same or different frequency can play any role in the ability to distinguish between two signals because at the receiver there is just one signal (or at least this is how i imagine it).

Comment: @hyportnex, Not necessarily. For example, a silicon photodetector isn't sensitive to wavelengths longer than about 1100 nm, even without any filter in front of it.

Comment: Take a bunch of series connected $L_kC_k$ resonators, $k=1,2,3,...$, and each resonates at $\omega_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt {L_kC_k}}$, and connect those LC pairs in parallel and drive them together. If you do it right, proper load/source impedance, low loss, etc., and $\omega_k$ are sufficiently separated then they will respond essentially independently from each other in the sense that each will "pick" out the spectral content around its own resonant frequency.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question is perfectly clear and has  good answer below.

Comment: "My imagination about EM waves is that they sum together" , EM waves  are not water waves, because they can exist in vacuum moving with velocity c and no medium, in contrast to  the way water  and acoustic waves work.Two beams of light in vacuum pass through each other without interacting, no superposition.

Comment: I will vote to reopen because maybe somebody else will take the trouble to answer

Comment: @annav i don't want to bother ppl anymore with my questions because i feel i need first to learn much more but when i just quickly googled i found this - "The superposition principle is a fundamental concept in physics, especially in wave mechanics. It states that when two or more waves interact in a medium, the resultant wave is simply the algebraic sum of their individual waves. This principle is also applicable to electromagnetic waves."

Comment: Note the "in a medium". For  EM waves this means when going through matter,  glass, water etc, then there is a medium on which they interact again in a different mathematical way then the water or sound waves, that has to be studied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If i have two different EM waves (different frequencies) then i can observer just the amplitude of sum of these waves no?

No. At radio frequencies we can produce signals on wires that contain all the frequency and phase information present in the free-space wave over a similar band. We aren't limited to representing only the amplitude or total energy impinging on an antenna.

At optical frequencies we can use various optical filters to isolate particular bands. We can also use detectors that are sensitive only to specific bands. More esoterically we can use nonlinear optical devices to manipulate optical signals and determine the phase of an optical signal.

> I know that this is not true otherwise we would not be able to have radios,

In a conventional radio, the "detector" (actually the antenna) collects all the signals across a wide band of frequencies and produces an output voltage or current signal that contains all of those signals. Then mixers and filters are used on that signal to isolate the desired band on which a particular sender is found.

In comments you added:

> I know our eyes are "detectors" too but i can't figure out how it can work

Your eyes contain three different chemical [receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opsin). Each chemical is sensitive to a different range of optical frequencies, so that you detect (crudely) red, green, and blue separately. Your brain then combines the signals from the different receptors in the eye to give you the experience of different colors formed by different ratios of the receptors being stimulated at each point on the retina.

Comment: ... we can produce signals on wires that contain all the frequency and phase information present in the free-space wave over a similar band. We aren't limited to representing only the amplitude or total energy impinging on an antenna. - This is what i need to get deeper into. I imagine the wave at particular point through the time like a sequence of numbers, each number being sum of amplitudes of underlying waves but no way to determine the waves. I know it is not like how i imagine it but in past two days i tried to figure out how it really works and i didn't. Im stupid i guess :D

Comment: @designerrr, you are correct that you cannot extract frequency (or phase) information from a single sample of a signal. You must observe the signal for a period of time to do that. The longer you observe, the more precisely you will be able to distinguish frequencies in the signal. But this is not specific to EM waves --- for example, you also can't tell what note is being played from a single sample of the air pressure in a sound wave.

Comment: @designerrr The sequence of numbers model is the basis of "software-defined radio", a very useful approach to radio communication. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio

Answer (score 1):

Separating colours is the job of [spectroscopes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectroscopy), the oldest of which is [Newton’s prism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersive_prism).